# Get custom values from an php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this big array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [group_id] => 87 
[group_name] => Étel jellemzők 
[group_slug] => etel_jellemzok 
[group_desc] => [attributes] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [attr_id] => 88 
[attr_name] => csípős [attr_slug] => csipos [attr_desc] => [value] => yes ) 
[1] => Array ( [attr_id] => 89 [attr_name] => gluténmentes [attr_slug] => glutenmentes [attr_desc] => [value] => yes ) 
[2] => Array ( [attr_id] => 90 [attr_name] => tejmentes [attr_slug] => tejmentes [attr_desc] => [value] => yes ) 
[3] => Array ( [attr_id] => 91 [attr_name] => új [attr_slug] => uj [attr_desc] => [value] => yes ) ) ) 
[1] => Array ( [group_id] => 92 [group_name] => Allergének [group_slug] => allergenek [group_desc] => [attributes] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [attr_id] => 93
[attr_name] => laktóz [attr_slug] => laktoz [attr_desc] => [value] => yes )
[1] => Array ( [attr_id] => 94 [attr_name] => glutén [attr_slug] => gluten [attr_desc] => [value] => yes )
[2] => Array ( [attr_id] => 95 [attr_name] => diófélék [attr_slug] => diofelek [attr_desc] => [value] => yes )
[3] => Array ( [attr_id] => 96 [attr_name] => szója [attr_slug] => szoja [attr_desc] => [value] => yes ) ) ) )
```

How can I return all attr_name and their values only?

Comment: `array_column($array[0]['group_desc']['attributes'], 'attr_name');`, maybe, but it's hard to read that poorly formatted array.  Plus I would prefer, `var_export` to `print_r` but whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (Un-tested):

```
array_column($array[0]['attributes'], 'value', 'attr_name');
```